# Doxygen or ctags for extracting methods from c++ code base?

Tags: c++, unix, doxygen, ctags

How do you use doxygen or ctags on HP-UX to list all classes and methods from C++ code base.
I believe ctags comes along with HP-UX but doxygen need to be installed?

An example would help.

Comment: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/index.html

Comment: `ctags` that comes packaged with HP-UX is probably outdated and doesn't support C++.